# file schema.graphqls is not recognized as a grahql file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-graphql

I'm trying to use graphql for the first time, and I have a problem with the schema.graphqls file, in fact the extension is not recognized even in my pom.xml I added the dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try `com.graphql-java` as groupId

Comment: what do you mean the extension is not recognized? Maybe your IDE doesn't support this type of files? Which Spring Boot version are you using? Where is that schema file located in your project?

Answer (score 0):

it should be `schema.graphql`, not `schema.graphqls`